# How to sort list by POJO property in descending order?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have  POJO class Student like this

```
class Student
{
    private int score;
    private String FirstName;
    //Getters and setters .................
}
```

I am creating ArrayList like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Student> al_students= new ArrayList<Student>();
    Student s1= new Student();
    s1.setScore(90);
    s1.setFirstName("abc");
    al_students.add(s1);

    Student s2= new Student();
    s2.setScore(95);
    s2.setFirstName("def");
    al_students.add(s2);

    Student s3= new Student();
    s3.setScore(85);
    s3.setFirstName("xyz");
    al_students.add(s3);
}
```

Now I want to sort it based on scores in descending order i.e
output

```
1)def      95
2)abc      90
3)xyz      85
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a custom `Comparator`.

Here's a full example (imports excluded):

```
public class Main {

    // main method setting up and printing students
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setScore(90);
        s1.setFirstName("abc");
        students.add(s1);

        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setScore(95);
        s2.setFirstName("def");
        students.add(s2);

        Student s3 = new Student();
        s3.setScore(85);
        s3.setFirstName("xyz");
        students.add(s1);
        System.out.printf("Unordered: %s%n", students);
        // sorting using anonymous Comparator
        Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {
            public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                // notice the cast to (Integer) to invoke compareTo
                return ((Integer)s1.getScore()).compareTo(s2.getScore());
            }
        });
        System.out.printf("Ordered: %s%n", students);
    }
    // Student class
    static class Student {
        private int score;
        private String firstName;
        // boring stuff
        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String name) {
            this.firstName = name;
        }
        // for printing
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Student \"%s\" with score: %d%n", firstName,
                    score);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Unordered: [Student "abc" with score: 90
, Student "def" with score: 95
, Student "abc" with score: 90
]
Ordered: [Student "abc" with score: 90
, Student "abc" with score: 90
, Student "def" with score: 95
]
```

**Note**

As others mention, you can also `implement Comparable<Student>` in your `Student` class, if the only (or default) sorting will be by score.#

**Second edit**

In order to sort in a decreasing order, you can replace the `return` statement in your `Comparator` with the following:

```
return ((Integer)s2.getScore()).compareTo(s1.getScore());
```

Thanks [programminglover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4814174/programminglover) for spotting this / apologies for mistakenly rejecting the edit!

Answer (score 12):

Use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
    Collections.sort(al_students, new Comparator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o2.getScore(), o1.getScore());
        }           
    });
```

Alternatively, have Student implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface:

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        return Integer.compare(s.getScore(), getScore());
    }
}
```

Then you can just sort without the Comparator:

```
Collections.sort(al_students);
```

Comment: To compare `int` you can use `Integer.compare(int1, int2)`. There is no need to box `int` to `Integer` just to call `compareTo`.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, I'm more used to C# where you can just call `.compareTo` on an `int`.

Comment: i think My JDK 6  version is not supporting it but Some part of your answer have  helped me that's why I am upvoting you and marking @Mena answer correct I am very thankful of you for your efforts

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Java 8 then your code can look like

```
al_students.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getScore).reversed());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

See, Have this logic. 
Student is a class which you've created. And If you want to allow some other class to sort your custom objects in your own requirements, you should tell it. And that's gonna happen if you implement either Comparable or Comparator interface and override those method in your custom class and in those methods you specify how you are gonna compare.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the entire question is answered by others....

Since there are 2 options, either to use Comparable interface or Comparator interface, 
I would like you to go to [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) explaining when to use Comparable and when to use Comparator.

That will be really helpful to you.